# Can I write this for loop in a more compact way with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to clean up this type of loop using LINQ? I really think this method should be a one liner with LINQ. But I do not get it..

My Method looks like this:

```
int[] MakeList(int stepWidth)
{
    var ret = new List<int>();
    for (var i=0;i<360;i+=stepWidth)
    {
        ret.Add(i);
    }

    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

The only solution I could figure out was:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 360).Where(x => x % stepWidth == 0).ToArray();
```

But this Enumerabl.Range(0,360) looks a little too crude to me :)

Comment: The answer is no and not really above what you have. and besides don't be afraid of readable code.

Comment: I don't think your solution is crude. It does what you want, and you will always need the stepWidth aspect.

Comment: @TheGeneral : I think this depends on what you prefer.. I really like LINQ and I think a linq expression would be faster to read than my MakeList method..

Comment: You could speed it up a tiny bit. `Enumerable.Range(0, 360 / stepWidth).Select(x => x * stepWidth).ToArray()`

Comment: I think it's perfectly clear enough as it is, but if that's something that you call a lot it can certainly be optimised so that it only creates a single array and doesn't create a list and then copy the contents of that list to an array...

Comment: @Matthew I looked at C# source code, and apparently `List<T>` is internally implemented as an array, and from `ToArray()` that internal array will be returned. So there is no final copy, but there still is a dynamic array expansion, which is prevented if we created the array by ourselves.

Comment: @Dialecticus No, that's not right at all. If that were the case, changing data inside the array returned from `ToArray()` would also change the data in the list, which it doesn't (thankfully)!

Comment: @Matthew, hmm indeed. I looked at it again and a new array is created from internal `Buffer` struct. Who knows what I saw the first time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of `.Select` and `.TakeWhile` could be one approach, but it looks very close to other approaches

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                       .Select(i => i * step)
                       .TakeWhile(i => i < 360)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Ironically, if you count up all the non-whitespace characters in the Linq approach, it's actually longer than the OP's code (*and* harder to read, IMO).

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I think (IMO :)), `TakeWhile` is more descriptive about intentions and even it is longer it will iterates only required amount of times, where `Where` will iterate all numbers within range.

Answer (score 1):

First: your code is nice and readable.

Second: don't be afraid of loops - loops perfectly show programmer intentions. If I had to change something, I would eliminate `List<i>`:

```
int[] MakeList(int stepWidth)
{
    var length = (360 + stepWidth - 1) / stepWidth;
    var ret = new int[length];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = i * stepWidth;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Third: if LINQ is used frequently, I would return `IEnumerable<int>` (see generators):

```
IEnumerable<int> MakeSequence(int step)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += step)
        yield return i;
}
```

And use it as follows: `MakeSequence(x).ToArray()` or `MakeSequence(x).[SomeLinqMethods]`.

Comment: This actually doesn't return the right result for some values of `stepWidth`. For example, try it with `stepWidth ==7` and compare it to the OP's results. It will return one less value. The actual count needs to be rounded up, for example `(360 + stepWidth - 1) / stepWidth`

Comment: Thanks Matthiew, you're right. Corrected. Generator checked, works as expected.